# PDF File size of 50kb increases dramatically up to 9mb after signing it with previously using Itext Java Application

Tags: certificate, itext, digital-signature

I was a using a custom build itext based java application for digitally signing pdf files.

Every thing was working fine for last one year but recently the size of the output signed pdf file drastically increasing up to 10 MB for just a 50kb source pdf file.

Earlier for a 50 kb file ,the output was  less than 300 kb.

Kindly find the code snippets

```
public void sign(String src, String dest,
        Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
        String digestAlgorithm, String provider, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard subfilter,
        String reason, String location,
        Collection<CrlClient> crlList,
        OcspClient ocspClient,
        TSAClient tsaClient,
        int estimatedSize)
                throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating the reader and the stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
    // Creating the appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

    ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
}

public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String DLL,String PIN,String usage) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    LoggerFactory.getInstance().setLogger(new SysoLogger());

    String config = "name=eToken\n" + "library=" + DLL + "\n";
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
    Provider providerPKCS11 = new SunPKCS11(bais);
    Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);
    //System.out.println(providerPKCS11.getName());
    BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(providerBC);
    PrivateKey pk = null;  
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");

    try{
        ks.load(null, PIN.toCharArray());
        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();

        java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

        while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliases.nextElement();
            //System.out.println(alias);
            X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
            final boolean[] keyUsage = c.getKeyUsage();
            if(usage=="0" &&(keyUsage[0] || keyUsage[1]))
            {
                //System.out.println("Digital Signature");
                pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, PIN.toCharArray());
                this.providerPKCS11 = providerPKCS11.getName();
                this.pub_key = c;
                this.chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

                for (int i = 0; i < this.chain.length; i++) {
                    // System.out.println(chain[i]);
                    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)chain[i];
                    String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
                    if (tsaUrl != null) {
                        tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));
            }
            else if(usage=="2" &&keyUsage[2])
            {
                //System.out.println("Encryption");
                pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, PIN.toCharArray());
                this.pub_key = c;
            }

            //alias1=alias;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Key Store Not loaded .. PIN entered may be incorrect");
    }

    return pk;
}
```

Main function is

```
token.sign("D:\\15 SAMPLE PDF FILES\\15 SAMPLE PDF FILES\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName(), "D:\\15 SAMPLE PDF FILES\\15 SAMPLE PDF FILES\\sign\\singn_"+listOfFiles[i].getName(), token.chain, PK_sign, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, token.providerPKCS11, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS,
                "Sign", "Kottayam", token.crlList, token.ocspClient, token.tsaClient, 0);
```

Last week our firewall changed. Is that the problem?

Comment: Can you be more vague?

Comment: Last week our firewall changed. Is that the problem

Comment: It is a java application using itextpdf library, primarily used for decrypting a public key encrypted pdf and adding a digital signature to it before delivery

Comment: As you don't show your code and an example of a big signed file, we can but guess. But yes, a firewall change can make a difference if you sign with embedded validation related information: If earlier on the OCSP servers of your PKI could be used and now instead CRLs have to be used, the required additional file size might explode.

Comment: How to check and confirm whether the problem is with firewall. Can i try both url of ocsp and crl server for connection

Comment: Parsing the generated PDF could be an option. ~9.7 MB of data should be easy to find in  a 10 MB file.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your support. It was because of the firewall change. Initially the server will not look for crl url and so it doesnt embedd crl since it is not connecting to internet because of the firewall authentication. Unfortunately the firewall change cleared all the authentication and hence the server got the internet access and crl embedds in the signature.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer. Looking at your code, this kind of behavior isn't that easy to predict so it could certainly be useful for others falling into the same hole. @mkl Could do the same of course; I guess mkl first indicated the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the process of signing a PDF suddenly results in much bigger files than before, the reason often is related to embedded validation related information, in particular to embedded CRLs (certificate revocation lists) which may be very large.

The cause might be purely inside the PKI. E.g. if lots of certificates suddenly are revoked after the associated signature creation devices have been found to be insecure, a formerly small CRL may suddenly become very large.

It might also be a matter of connectivity. For example

- if the OCSP responder of the PKI was accessible before but suddenly isn't anymore, the signing process might use the CRL instead; or
- if the revocation information was not accessible at all before and suddenly is, the signing process also might start using the CRL.

As it turned out, the latter was the case here, as the OP reported:

> It was because of the firewall change. Initially the server will not look for crl url and so it doesnt embedd crl since it is not connecting to internet because of the firewall authentication. Unfortunately the firewall change cleared all the authentication and hence the server got the internet access and crl embedds in the signature.

Something like this can be prevented by disallowing use of CRLs. In the case at hand, the `Collection<CrlClient> crlList` parameter of the `sign` method can simply be left empty.

Essentially, if you don't want to include CRLs or OCSP responses, don't provide the signing process with means to request them.